# Using Getaxis to move an object with both mouse and arrows keys along the x axis in c#/Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Background: I am making a breakout clone. I have a script for the paddle that successfully moves the paddle along the X axis with mouse movement.

Desire:  I want to have two inputs for this game.  one is the mouse, The other input is the left and right arrow keys.  I went into Edit----> Project settings----> input, but I'm unsure how to adjust the Alt Negative, Alt positive buttons to align with the mouse on x axis.

I also would like to clamp movement based upon the size of my game screen. I know I must use Mathfclamp method, however I'm not certain how to go about formatting that in the correct order in my script.

Here is the code I used for GetAxis.

```
public class Paddle : MonoBehaviour {


   public float speed;


    void Update () 
    {
        float x = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")* Time.deltaTime*speed;


        transform.Translate (x,0,0);

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `Input.GetAxis` with the arrow keys but there is a trick on how to do this. First, use `Input.GetAxis` to get the mouse move value and store it to variable `x`. If the `x` value is **more** or **less** than **0** then move the Object with the value from `Input.GetAxis`.

If the `x` value is **0**, check if the left or right arrow is pressed and then make the direction of `x` to be `Vector3.right*speed` or `Vector3.left.x * keySpeed` depending on which key was pressed. Another thing to know is that both speed multipliers must be different values. There should be a speed multiplier for the mouse and another one for the keyboard or the Object will disappear from  the screen. The appropriate value for the mouse is `100f` and for keyboard is `0.1f`.

```
public class Paddle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float mouseSpeed = 100;
    public float keySpeed = 0.1f;


    void Update()
    {
        float x = 0;
        x = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * Time.deltaTime * mouseSpeed;

        if (x == 0)
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
            {
                x = Vector3.left.x * keySpeed;
            }

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
            {
                x = Vector3.right.x * keySpeed;
            }

        }
        transform.Translate(x, 0, 0);
    }
}
```